# How do I use bitwise operators on a "double" on C++?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I was asked to get the internal binary representation of different types in C. My program currently works fine with 'int' but I would like to use it with "double" and "float". My code looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
string findBin(T x) {
string binary;
for(int i = 4096 ; i >= 1; i/=2) {
        if((x & i) != 0) binary += "1";
        else binary += "0";
}
    return binary;
}
```

The program fails when I try to instantiate the template using a "double" or a "float".

Comment: What output do you expect when using a double and/or float?

Comment: @Nathan: Anything if the bit is a 1 and 0 if the bit is a zero.

Comment: Just something I thought you might find interesting: some systems (esp. Linux) have an ieee754.h header with unions `ieee754_float` and `ieee754_double` that define (endian safe) bitfields for reading the exponent, mantissa, sign-bit (negative), not-a-number bit etc.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Succinctly, you don't.

The bitwise operators do not make sense when applied to `double` or `float`, and the standard says that the bitwise operators (`~`, `&`, `|`, `^`, `>>`, `<<`, and the assignment variants) do not accept `double` or `float` operands.

Both `double` and `float` have 3 sections - a sign bit, an exponent, and the mantissa.  Suppose for a moment that you could shift a `double` right.  The exponent, in particular, means that there is no simple translation to shifting a bit pattern right - the sign bit would move into the exponent, and the least significant bit of the exponent would shift into the mantissa, with completely non-obvious sets of meanings.  In IEEE 754, there's an implied 1 bit in front of the actual mantissa bits, which also complicates the interpretation.

Similar comments apply to any of the other bit operators.

So, because there is no sane or useful interpretation of the bit operators to `double` values, they are not allowed by the standard.

---

From the comments:

> I'm only interested in the binary representation. I just want to print it, not do anything useful with it.

This code was written several years ago for SPARC (big-endian) architecture.

```
#include <stdio.h>

union u_double
{
    double  dbl;
    char    data[sizeof(double)];
};

union u_float
{
    float   flt;
    char    data[sizeof(float)];
};

static void dump_float(union u_float f)
{
    int exp;
    long mant;

    printf("32-bit float: sign: %d, ", (f.data[0] & 0x80) >> 7);
    exp = ((f.data[0] & 0x7F) << 1) | ((f.data[1] & 0x80) >> 7);
    printf("expt: %4d (unbiassed %5d), ", exp, exp - 127);
    mant = ((((f.data[1] & 0x7F) << 8) | (f.data[2] & 0xFF)) << 8) | (f.data[3] & 0xFF);
    printf("mant: %16ld (0x%06lX)\n", mant, mant);
}

static void dump_double(union u_double d)
{
    int exp;
    long long mant;

    printf("64-bit float: sign: %d, ", (d.data[0] & 0x80) >> 7);
    exp = ((d.data[0] & 0x7F) << 4) | ((d.data[1] & 0xF0) >> 4);
    printf("expt: %4d (unbiassed %5d), ", exp, exp - 1023);
    mant = ((((d.data[1] & 0x0F) << 8) | (d.data[2] & 0xFF)) << 8) | (d.data[3] & 0xFF);
    mant = (mant << 32) | ((((((d.data[4] & 0xFF) << 8) | (d.data[5] & 0xFF)) << 8) | (d.data[6] & 0xFF)) << 8) | (d.data[7] & 0xFF);
    printf("mant: %16lld (0x%013llX)\n", mant, mant);
}

static void print_value(double v)
{
    union u_double d;
    union u_float  f;

    f.flt = v;
    d.dbl = v;

    printf("SPARC: float/double of %g\n", v);
//    image_print(stdout, 0, f.data, sizeof(f.data));
//    image_print(stdout, 0, d.data, sizeof(d.data));
    dump_float(f);
    dump_double(d);
}


int main(void)
{
    print_value(+1.0);
    print_value(+2.0);
    print_value(+3.0);
    print_value( 0.0);
    print_value(-3.0);
    print_value(+3.1415926535897932);
    print_value(+1e126);
    return(0);
}
```

The commented out 'image_print()` function prints an arbitrary set of bytes in hex, with various minor tweaks.  Contact me if you want the code (see my profile).

If you're using Intel (little-endian), you'll probably need to tweak the code to deal with the reverse bit order.  But it shows how you can do it - using a `union`.

Comment: I understand how double and float are structured at the bits level, but I'm only interested in the binary representation. I just want to print it, not do anything useful with it.

Comment: @Juan: how come binary representation is different from bit level structuring? I don't understand your comment.

Comment: `<<` and `>>` could be defined as multiplication and division by 2, which for `double` would mean incrementing/decrementing the exponent field.  `&`, `|`, and `^` would be far less simple.

Comment: "...there is no sane or useful interpretation of the bit operators to double values..." **False.** Downvote.

Comment: @Andrew: would you care to explain?

Comment: Easy. Who are you to say that there's no sane or useful purpose to examining or playing with the bits in double values? As if you know all possible usages of doubles and bits in all possible software in order to make such a statement.

Comment: @Andrew: The `~` operator requires an integer operand; the bitwise `&`, `|`, `^` operators require integer operands; the shift operators require integer operands.  If you overload an operator for a specific class, then maybe you can do something, but you can't overload the operators for built-in types, AFAIK.  Therefore, there's no way to fiddle the bits of a `double` value using the bitwise operators on a `double` value.  You have to coerce the `double` into some other representation to be able to apply the bitwise operators to it.

Comment: That's not the point. The point was about your statement, which is false.

Comment: @Andrew: We're going to have to agree to disagree, then.  Thank you for trying to explain.  I think you failed, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Your answer was justifying that there is no such functionality provided *because* there is no sane or useful purpose for using it. AnT sufficiently explains the real reason that this functionality is (or at least should be) lacking in his answer. Your opinion is wrong, just like most people who use the phrase "agree to disagree" and "just my opinion" after a case is made.

Comment: The bitwise shifting operators were so useful to serialize/deserialize data without being dependent of the platform endianness. But if we are to serialize/deserialize `double` values, since the `<<` and `>>` operators are not available, we lose this possiblity, which is a shame. We do not really care that the resulting value has no meaning, we only want a bit shift, no matter what the data type is...

Answer (score 12):

You cannot directly apply bitwise operators to `float` or `double`, but you can still access the bits indirectly by putting the variable in a `union` with a character array of the appropriate size, then reading the bits from those characters.  For example:

```
string BitsFromDouble(double value) {
    union {
        double doubleValue;
        char   asChars[sizeof(double)];
    };

    doubleValue = value; // Write to the union

    /* Extract the bits. */
    string result;
    for (size i = 0; i < sizeof(double); ++i)
        result += CharToBits(asChars[i]);
    return result;
}
```

You may need to adjust your routine to work on chars, which usually don't range up to 4096, and there may also be some weirdness with endianness here, but the basic idea should work.  It won't be cross-platform compatible, since machines use different endianness and representations of doubles, so be careful how you use this.

Answer (score 4):

Bitwise operators don't generally work with "binary representation" (also called *object representation*) of *any* type. Bitwise operators work with *value representation* of the type, which is generally different from object representation. That applies to `int` as well as to `double`.

If you really want to get to the internal binary representation of an object of any type, as you stated in your question, you need to reinterpret the object of that type as an array of `unsigned char` objects and then use the bitwise operators on these `unsigned char`s

For example

```
double d = 12.34;
const unsigned char *c = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(&d);
```

Now by accessing elements `c[0]` through `c[sizeof(double) - 1]` you will see the internal representation of type `double`. You can use bitwise operations on these `unsigned char` values, if you want to.

Note, again, that in general case in order to access internal representation of type `int` you have to do the same thing. It generally applies to *any* type other than `char` types.

Answer (score 3):

Do a bit-wise cast of a pointer to the double  to `long long *` and dereference.
Example:

```
inline double bit_and_d(double* d, long long mask) {
  long long t = (*(long long*)d) & mask;
  return *(double*)&t;
}
```

Edit: This is almost certainly going to run afoul of gcc's enforcement of strict aliasing. Use one of the various workarounds for that. (`memcpy`, unions, `__attribute__((__may_alias__))`, etc)

Comment: oops. I need to look at what I sumbit =/

Comment: @Andrew sizeof(double) is 8. That's 64b. Not sure where you're getting 16B from.

Answer (score 1):

Other solution is to get a pointer to the floating point variable and cast it to a pointer to integer type of the same size, and then get value of the integer this pointer points to. Now you have an integer variable with same binary representation as the floating point one and you can use your bitwise operator.

```
string findBin(float f) {
    string binary;
    for(long i = 4096 ; i >= 1; i/=2) {
        long x = * ( long * ) &y;
        if((x & i) != 0) binary += "1";
        else binary += "0";
    }
    return binary;
}
```

But remember: you have to cast to a type with same size. Otherwise unpredictable things may happen (like buffer overflow, access violation etc.).

Comment: Even better: long x = * reinterpret_cast<long *> (& y);

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can use a bitwise operator on a double by casting `double*` to `long long*` (or sometimes just `long*`).

```
int main(){
    double * x = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
    *x = -5.12345;
    printf("%f\n", *x);
    *((long*)x) &= 0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
    printf("%f\n", *x);
    return 0;
}
```

On my computer, this code prints:

```
-5.123450
5.123450
```