# How to perform sum between double with bitwise operations

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'd like to know how floating-point numbers sum works.
How can I sum two double(or float) numbers using bitwise operations?

Comment: Do you know how floating point numbers are represented, like IEEE-754?

Comment: Look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743115/how-do-i-use-bitwise-operators-on-a-double-on-c

Comment: @matekm This question is different. This question is about implementing floating-point addition.

Comment: Possibly too broad for this site. Google "how floating point arithmetic is implemented". Lots of good results.

Answer (score 8):

Short answer: if you need to ask, you are not going to implement floating-point addition from bitwise operators. It is completely possible but there are a number of subtle points that you would need to have asked about before. You could start by implementing a double → float conversion function, it is simpler but would introduce you to many of the concepts. You could also do double → nearest integer as an [exercise](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/03/nearbyintf2).

Nevertheless, here is the naive version of addition:

Use large arrays of bits for each of the two operands (254 + 23 for `float`, 2046 + 52 for `double`). Place the significand at the right place in the array according to the exponent. Assuming the arguments are both normalized, do not forget to place the implicit leading 1. Add the two arrays of bits with the usual rules of [binary addition](http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-addition/). Then convert the resulting array to floating-point format: first look for the leftmost 1; the position of this leftmost 1 determines the exponent. The significand of the result starts right after this leading 1 and is respectively 23- or 52-bit wide. The bits after that determine whether the value should be rounded up or down.

Although this is the naive version, it is already quite complicated.

The non-naive version does not use 2100-bit wide arrays, but takes advantage of a couple of “guard bits” instead (see section “on rounding” in [this document](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~markhill/cs354/Fall2008/notes/flpt.apprec.html)).

The additional subtleties include:

- The sign bits of the arguments can mean that the magnitudes should be subtracted for an addition, or added for a subtraction.
- One of the arguments can be NaN. Then the result is NaN.
- One of the arguments can be an infinity. If the other argument is finite or the same infinity, the result is the same infinity. Otherwise, the result is NaN.
- One of the arguments can be a denormalized number. In this case there is no leading 1 when transferring the number to the array of bits for addition.
- The result of the addition can be an infinity: depending on the details of the implementation, this would be recognized as an exponent too large to fit the format, or an overflow during the addition of the binary arrays (the overflow can also occur during the rounding step).
- The result of the addition can be a denormalized number. This is recognized as the absence of a leading 1 in the first 2046 bits of the array of bits. In this case the last 52 bits of the array should be transferred to the significand of the result, and the exponent should be set to zero, to indicate a denormalized result.

Comment: +1 for "if you need to ask". It's one of those questions where the answer for people who ask is different.

Comment: @gnasher729 I wondered for 3 minutes whether I wanted to close as “too broad” or to answer, and I only started answering because I did not realize how complex even the simple method would turn out to be. Still, it would be a good question if it was from someone who had started and who was confused about one of the many difficulties.