# Difference between | and || , or & and &&

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

These are two simple samples in C++ written on Dev-cpp C++ 5.4.2:

```
float a, b, c;

if (a | b  & a | c)
   printf("x = %.2f\tF = %.0f\n", x, F);
else
   printf("x = %.2f\tF = %.2f\n", x, F);
```

and this code :

```
float a, b, c;

if (a || b  && a || c)
   printf("x = %.2f\tF = %.0f\n", x, F);
else
   printf("x = %.2f\tF = %.2f\n", x, F);
```

Can somebody tell my difference between `||` > `|` and `&` > `&&`. The second code works , but first does not.
And compiler gives an error message :

> [Error] invalid operands of types 'float' and 'float' to binary 'operator&'.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C

Comment: One could get some starting point from there, about pointers and comparison operators
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison and
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: I find it weird C++ doesn't allow bitwise operations on floats, although one can say they don't make much sense, these are still bit sequences, and one can do arithmetic on them.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem By this logic, to support binary operations they would need to add a new type e.g. `binary32`, `binary64` etc. and a set of converting functions. They are semantically different in c++ but one does not see it, because they are not syntactically different from integers. Having said that, some smart people went that way e.g. C#. It's not an obvious design decision IMO.

Comment: [How do I use bitwise operators on a “double” on C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4743115/995714), [How to perform a bitwise operation on floating point numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1723575/995714)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The operators `|`, `&`, and `~` act on individual bits in parallel.  They can be used only on integer types.  `a | b` does an independent OR operation of each bit of `a` with the corresponding bit of `b` to generate that bit of the result.

The operators `||`, `&&`, and `!` act on each entire operand as a single `true`/`false` value.  Any data type can be used that implicitly converts to `bool`.  Many data types, including `float` implicitly convert to bool with an implied `!=0` operation.

`||` and `&&` also "short circuit".  That means whenever the value of the result can be determined by just the first operand, the second is not evaluated.  Example:

`ptr && (*ptr==7)`  If `ptr` is zero, the result is false without any risk of seg faulting by dereferencing zero.

You could contrast that with `(int)ptr & (*ptr)`.  Ignoring the fact that this would be a bizarre operation to even want, if `(int)ptr` were zero, the entire result would be zero, so a human might think you don't need the second operand in that case.  But the program will likely compute both anyway.

Answer (score 8):

You seems be confused with the symbols of the operators. Theses symbols are actually split in two different categories, which are **bit-wise operators** and **logical operators**. Although they use the same symbols, you should regard them as different operators. The truth tables for both categories are similar, but the meanings are different. Maybe that's why people use the similar symbols for the operators.

[**bit-wise operators**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

```
~  // NOT
&  // AND
|  // OR
^  // XOR
```

The bit-wise operators will regard all its operands as binary numerals and act according to the bit-wise truth tables on every bit of the operands.

```
Bit-wise Truth Table

x   y   x&y x|y x^y
0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   1   1
0   1   0   1   1
1   1   1   1   0

x   ~x
0   1
1   0
```

[**logical operators**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)

```
!   // Logical NOT (negation)
&&  // Logical AND (conjunction)
||  // Logical OR  (disjunction)
```

The logical operator will regard all its operands as bools and act according the operator truth tables. Any number that is not equal to `0` will be `true`, else will be `false`.

```
Logical Truth Table

x   y    x&&y   x||y
F   F    F      F
T   F    F      T
F   T    F      T
T   T    T      T

x   !x
F   T
T   F
```

---

For example:

```
int a = 10;  // a = 0000 .... 0000 1010  <-- a 32 bits integer
             // a is not zero -> true
int b = 7;   // b = 0000 .... 0000 0111  <-- a 32 bits integer
             // b is not zero -> true
```

Then for bit-wise operator:

```
assert(a & b == 2);   // 2 = 0000 .... 0000 0010  <-- every bit will & separately
```

For logic operator:

```
assert(a && b == true);  // true && true -> true
```

Answer (score 3):

The *bitwise operators*, which are `|` (OR), `&` (AND), `^` (XOR), and `~` (complement) do what you expect them to do: they perform the aforementioned operations on bits.
And regarding your compilation issue, [there are no bitwise operations for floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723575/how-to-perform-a-bitwise-operation-on-floating-point-numbers).

The *logical operators*, which are `||` (OR), `&&` (AND), and `!` (NOT) only know the values `true` and `false`.
An expression is `true` if its value is not `0`. It is `false` if its value equals `0`.
The logical operators do this operation first. Then they perform their corresponding operation:

- `||`: `true` if at least one the operands is `true`
- `&&`: `true` if both operands are `true`
- `!`: `true` if the operand is `false`

**Note** that [all logical operators are *short-circuit* operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344305/what-is-short-circuiting-and-how-is-it-used-when-programming-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

## Bitwise operation is not supported for floating points

Alternatively if you really need to check, you can cast before you use them (highly discouraged),

Check here how to convert a float into integrals, [https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/round.html](https://www.cs.tut.fi/%7Ejkorpela/round.html)

Comment: Thank you all very much! Your comments solved my problem =)