# Invalid read when using bitwise or

Tags: c, valgrind, bitwise-or

By accident, I wrote

```
if (var < 0 | List == NULL) {
   ...
}
```

where `var` is an `int` and List a `int*` (array of ints).

I meant to write

```
if (var < 0 || List == NULL) {
   ...
}
```

I know that

> The operators |, &, and ~ act on individual bits in parallel. They can
>   be used only on integer types. a | b does an independent OR operation
>   of each bit of a with the corresponding bit of b to generate that bit
>   of the result.

Quote from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34492501/difference-between-and-or-and/34492693).

What I don't understand is that [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (with option `--leak-check=full`) gave me the error `Invalid read of size 8` in the first case and no error in the second case.

I think the data access to `var` and `List` is the very same in both cases.

What type is the result of `List == NULL` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I think the data access to `var` and `List` is the very same in both
>   cases."

No, the difference is [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). With logical OR, the expression `List == NULL` will not be evaluated when `var < 0`.

But with bitwise-OR, you *will* evaluate `List == NULL` even when `var < 0`. Why that triggers an "Invalid read of size 8" is hard to say because you haven't shown enough of the code. But I suspect that `List` is not initialized when `var < 0`.