# if statement and --variable

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am working toward my C++ exam, and I am doing some past papers. Then I stumbeled over this code understanding task. And I am wondering, why doesn't value change to 4 in this if statement?

```
int found = 0, value = 5;
if (!found || --value == 0) {
    cout << "danger";
}
cout << "value =" << value << endl;
```

Comment: why should it change to 4 ?

Comment: You have read about [*short-circuit evaluation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)?

Comment: I have not read about short-circuit evaluation

Comment: Your first operation !found becomes true and its not executing --value . Learn about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34492501/difference-between-and-or-and

Comment: Did you try running this? `value` doesn't change to 4.

Comment: @BaumMitAugen: Why did you flip the meaning of the question? I know the question was incorrect before, but this could indicate a misunderstanding by OP.

Comment: @interjay I just rolled back to the first, correct revision of the question. For some reason, OP edited it to make it wrong. Botched test or something I guess, dunno.

Comment: @BaummitAugen OK, makes sense.

Answer (score 8):

```
if (!found || --value == 0)
```

In Logical OR operation, if first condition is satisfied, then it won't evaluate second condition. Here `!found` is TRUE and it won't execute `--value` thus leaving it's value as 5.

Answer (score 0):

Because if the first condition is satisfied, the second is not even considered to 
 evaluate. To get your expectations, swap the conditions.

```
int found = 0, value = 5;
if ( --value == 0 || !found) {
    cout << "danger";
}
cout << "value =" << value << endl;
```